# How to include postinst file with bzr builddeb?

Tags: package-management, ppa, deb, launchpad, bazaar

I have built a package for Ubuntu using the [Ubuntu Packaging Guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/). That worked fine until the point that I wanted to configure the package after installation. Usually debian packages get a postinst file to do that. `bzr dh-make` creates a `postinst.ex` file which seems not to be executed. I have added a `postinst` file but no matter what permissions and filename additions I try, the file seems not to be included nor executed. I'm using `bzr builddeb` to build the package.

How do I correctly include install scripts to my packages?

EDIT: Thanks to [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru)! I just needed to add the `debian/postinst` file with `bzr add`.

Comment: Does the built package contain a `postinst` file? Use `dpkg-deb` to examine the package file.

Comment: It does not. `dpkg-deb` doesn't show these files. I tried php5-sqlite. After extracting there is a file just named `postinst` in the debian dir. I have put a similar file in my debian dir but it seems not to be added to the package.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you need to add `postinst` to bzr using `bzr add` before it will be picked up while building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`bzr builddeb`](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/builddeb-plugin.html)'s options include:

```
--strict    Refuse to build if there are unknown files in the working tree, --no-strict disables the check.
```

This makes me think it will include only those files which are added to the branch while building a package. Therefore, try adding `postinst` using `bzr add`.